# Using both Django and Websocket

Tags: python, django, websocket

My issue comes as follows: I want to mount a game using only one port (80), and django.

For my game (it's not a MMORTS game, so I must have real-time interaction) I need to use Websockets. This means, I need to use Django (backend, profiles) + Websockets (The game itself). For the sake of this issue, think about this game as if it was like Habbo Hotel or Sims (I need that kind of interaction).

**Question**: What non-dead packages could I use for this?

If the recommended websockets-package is not integrable to Django but mountable as a separate server, I'd need to solve 2 additional issues:

1. Is there a way to bridge non-ws connections to the regular Django application handler?
2. Is there a way to integrate whatever I implement as the websocket handling (i.e. game logic) to the Django engine? (i.e. models).

Assume I'd use this in a shared hosting supporting Python 2.7/Django 1.6.

Comment: [Tornado Web Server](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/)?

Comment: I'll see. Can i mount it in a shared hosting? How can I integrate it to Django?